# How to change input language?

Tags: 14.04, gnome, system, system-settings, language-support

I want to be able to switch between my input languages, but I can't drag and drop the languages in language support because the languages seem to be greyed out, what should I do?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to go to Dash and select "**Text Entry**" as shown in the picture below

[image]

[image]

Then you have to press <kbd>+</kbd> button to add your preferred languages.

Answer (score 1):

In *Language Support* you can change the display language. The place to control the input language is *System Settings -> Text Entry*.

https://help.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-help/keyboard-layouts.html

Answer (score 0):

They are grayed out below `English`, because everything is available in English.

The drag and drop is the ordering in which a language is used. So you can display everything available in Irish, the remaining in German and everything that isn't available in German in English finally - or sth similar.

Answer (score 0):

now in 2021 it just `windows` key and `space`