# Problem after cloning disk

Tags: 14.04, partitioning, mount, disk, clone

I cloned my hdd with 14.04 on it to an ssd (to use the ssd as new sytem disk).
During cloning, the ssd was mounted as /dev/sdb1 at the point /media/backup .
Once cloned, I replaced the hdd by the ssd. Ubuntu starts, but now the keyboard is in qwerty instead of azerty, and the Amazon search add keeps showing in the launcher after restart, even after removing it. 
How do I change the keyboard layout ( currently I cannot select a layout) and how do I remove the Amazon add ?

EDIT:
Amazon removed.
But still problems with keyboard:
In keyboard layout I cannot select any option, and I have this bug:
the language symbols in right top of screen appears as"Fr" when asking password at startup, and the keyboard is in French. Once logged, "Fr" symbol vanishes and keyboard is in qwerty.

Comment: You could use the [installation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/) guide for a truly clean install. If that is what you mean by clean install

Comment: I did not clone the entire disk to do now a new install !

Comment: I have noticed that the keyboard layout is empty.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found that the problem was due to a corrupted file.
The answer is given in:

[How to fix Unity locked disabled settings?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/534135/how-to-fix-unity-locked-disabled-settings)

It prefectly solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To remove amazon shopping use  `sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-shopping`

To get azerty keyboard layout use `setxkbmap fr` in your terminal, or `loadkeys fr` if on a console

Comment: Will this be permanent ? I would prefer a solution that fixes permanently the keyboard layout console.

Comment: Does not work. Amazon still showing, and I have to retype  setxkbmap fr after every restart or put it in a config file. I would rather a solution that fixes my installation.

Comment: For a perminate solution to the keyboard see [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/342099/238718) answer

Comment: Yes you could use [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/513007/238718) answer to change to your perferred language